# How to create a Captcha with validation using Html and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am new one to Web Designing. Can anyone give me an idea about to create Captcha with refresh option or Reference link for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have one sample here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42842/Implementation-of-Captcha-in-Javascript

Answer (score 1):

this simple library is best practice and applicable sample  u can use for client side captcha

[Jquery Real Person](http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahakgupta/creating-captcha-code-with-javascript/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/captcha-image-in-Asp-Net/